# How can I modify the "Applies To" property of a Cell's Conditional Formatting rule using VBA?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2016, conditional-formatting

I'm attempting to use VBA to create a conditional formatting rule and apply it to multiple cells.

I've attempted this is by creating the rules for one cell only and then editing the appliesto property for each formatcondition object.  See here:

```
Sub test()

    Dim strRange As String
    Dim myRange As Range

    strRange = "$B$4,$B$9:$BS$9"

    With Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B4") 
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .FormatConditions.Add xlExpression, xlEqual, "=ISBLANK(RC)"
        .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = True
        .FormatConditions(1).AppliesTo = strRange
    End With


    End Sub
```

This doesn't seem to work because once it reaches the AppliesTo line it actually changes the value of the cell itself rather than modify the formatcondition's AppliesTo property.

What is the best way to modify the "Applies To" property of a cell's conditional formatting rule?

I know that I can modify my "with" statement to include the other cells that I want to modify; not just cell B4.  The problem with this is that the range() object can only accept a string argument that is no longer than 1024 characters.  And in truth I want to apply this rule to a massive number of noncontiguous cells that breaks that 1024 character limit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a `ModifyAppliesToRange` method [designed for this purpose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/formatcondition-modifyappliestorange-method-excel). You will also need to convert `strRange` to a Range object.

Replace
`.FormatConditions(1).AppliesTo = strRange`
with
`.FormatConditions(1).ModifyAppliesToRange Range(strRange)`

Comment: I'm so embarrassed.  I had Microsoft Excel's VBA object library open on a separate browser tab and completely overlooked the ModifyAppliesToRange method.  Thank you for pointing that out to me.  Works great.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, combined with Conditional Formatting applying to multiple areas after cutting and pasting cells.  E.g., (E4:G4, E6:G6, etc.).

Basically, I had to determine the extent of the ranges and then used ModifyAppliesToRange to update it.

```
Sub FixCondFormatDupRules()
'
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim MyList As ListObject
Dim lRows As Long
Dim rngData As Range
Dim rngRow1 As Range
Dim rngRow2 As Range
Dim rngRowLast As Range

Set ws = ActiveSheet
Set MyList = ws.ListObjects(1)  'Note this only captures the first table in the ActiveSheet.  Wouldn't work if >1 table.
Set rngData = MyList.DataBodyRange
lRows = rngData.Rows.Count
Set rngRow1 = rngData.Rows(1)
Set rngRow2 = rngData.Rows(2)
Set rngRowLast = rngData.Rows(lRows)

With ws.Range(rngRow2, rngRowLast)
    .FormatConditions.Delete
End With

' Expanding the Conditional Formatting AppliesTo range to the extent of the ranges and to include the entire table column.
For Each col In rngRow1.Columns
    For Each fc In Range(col.Address).FormatConditions
        Set FirstCell = col                              'Find upper-left cell (lowest row, lowest col)
        Set LastCell = Cells(rngRowLast.Row, col.Column) 'Find lower-right cell (highest row, highest col)
        For Each xCell In fc.AppliesTo.Cells
            If xCell.Column < FirstCell.Column Then Set FirstCell = Cells(FirstCell.Row, xCell.Column)
            If xCell.Column > LastCell.Column Then Set LastCell = Cells(LastCell.Row, xCell.Column)
            If xCell.Row < FirstCell.Row Then Set FirstCell = Cells(xCell.Row, FirstCell.Column)
            If xCell.Row > LastCell.Row Then Set LastCell = Cells(xCell.Row, LastCell.Column)
        Next xCell
        fc.ModifyAppliesToRange Range(FirstCell, LastCell)
    Next fc
Next col

rngRow1.Cells(1, 1).Select
Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```